# Slow tiles loading with Leaflet and React

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I had to replace a 3D world with a regular 2D map. I opted for Leaflet, using it with react-leaflet. The map most have some kind of dark theme (all black, with all the borders of continents in blue or similar). So far I've read that I need to use a TileLayer provider. I found one that has a matching base style, excepting the borders. And as far as I understand, to "style" those borders, I need a GeoJSON file, which I have. The issue with this is that as I move around the map or change the zoom, things work rather laggy. Tiles takes a few (but notable) milliseconds to load (without any fade animation), which may be acceptable at least for now, and the borders takes considerable more time to be rendered, severely affecting the user experience.

The GeoJSON file is rather large (10.3mb), so I think that may be the issue (i'm new to using maps, in general), since it has a *lot* of vectors, for all the land in the world. But I don't know what other alternatives may be available. Also it's the first time I use React. The goal is just to have the borders of a blue color, and the rest of the map in black. Any help will be appreciated.

I'm also open to other technologies or sources.

This is what the Map component looks like (at least the relevant part).

```
import landGeoJSON from '../../jsons/geojson-land.json';

const Maps = () => {

  const [ landData, setLandData ] = useState({
      loading: false,
      data: [],
      error: null
  });

  const landStyle = {
    color: '#00D',
  };

  if (landData.loading === true) {
    return <h1>Loading.</h1>
  }

  return (

    <>
    <MapContainer     
        center          = { [51.505, -0.09] }
        zoom            = { 4 }
        maxZoom         = { 13 }
        minZoom         = { 1 }
        scrollWheelZoom = { true }
        fadeAnimation   = { true } 
        style={{ height: '100vh' }}>
        <TileLayer url="https://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/dark_nolabels/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png"/>
        <GeoJSON data={landGeoJSON} style={landStyle} />
      </MapContainer>
    </>
  );
};
```